# Laravel: How can I edit user information and upload profile image at the same time?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've been trying to edit user information and upload profile image from the same form.
I was able to edit user information using the code below,

```
ProfileController.php
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('profile.profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('profile.editprofile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {      
        $user_form = $request->all();
        $user = Auth::user();

        unset($user_form['_token']);

        $user->fill($user_form)->save();

        return redirect('/profile');
    }
```

however, when I tried to upload profile image too(I added the profile_image column to the DB) and changed the code like this

```
ProfileController.php
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('profile.profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('profile.editprofile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {

        $user->id = $request->user()->id;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            if (is_file($user->image)) {
                Storage::delete('public/image/' . $user->image);
            }
            $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
            $user->image = basename($path);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->update();

        return redirect('/tests');
    }
```

Nothing gets edited or uploaded. I will just be redirected and no errors are shown.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I  see your HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->name = $request->name;

if (is_file($user->image)) {
                Storage::delete('public/image/' . $user->image);
}
```

This code was unnecessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you get redirected because of this lines:

```
$user = Auth::user();

    $user->update();

    return redirect('/tests');
```

first line is setting a new value into $user variable and next line is updating that with no new value! and then redirect to previous url

check if your image moved to 'public/image' or not